# Can't upload file by form data in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, file-upload, multer, multiple-forms

I am using multipart/form-data to send file from client to NodeJS server. In BE I using multer for save image. Every things is fine when i run my app in localhost. But after deploy to heroku, i cannot upload file and an error message is logged:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filename')`

Here is my back end code:

1. upload controller

```
const createNewCV = async (req, res) => {
  uploadCVFile.single("cvFile")(req, res, (err) => {
    let message;
    const userData = req.body;
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      message = "fail to upload cv file!";
      res.status(200).json({ success: false, message: message }); 

    }
    try {
      const link = `${DEFAULT_CV_PATH}${req.file.filename}`;  //req.file is undefined
      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return null;
    }
  });
};
```

2. Uploads service:

```
const storageFile = (folderPath) =>
  multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, folderPath);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = randomUnixSuffix() + path.extname(file.originalname);
      cb(null, file.originalname.split(".")[0] + "-" + uniqueSuffix);
    },
  });

const uploadCVFile = multer({ storage: storageFile(CV_FOLDER_PATH) });

module.exports = { uploadCVFile};
```

This is my uploads folder in BE: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z94Cy.png)